# Odoo 11 Custom Reports

Tags: xml, python-3.x, odoo-11, qweb

I am trying to create a purchase report of products, I already have the wizard which opens a form where I can choose start date, end date and vendor, for now I am having problem displaying those three fields in the report(blank page), can somebody point me of what I am doing wrong?[Wizard View Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iJnw.png)

#### purchase_report_wizard.py

```
    class PurchaseReportWizard(models.TransientModel):
        _name="purchase.report.wizard"

        start_date = fields.Date('Start Date') 
        end_date = fields.Date('End Date') 
        vendor_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string = 'Vendor Name',domain = "[('supplier','=', True)]")

        @api.multi
        @api.constrains('start_date','end_date')
        def check_date(self):
            if self.start_date and self.end_date and (self.start_date > self.end_date):
                raise ValidationError(
                    _('End date should be greater than start date.')
                )


        @api.multi
        def print_pdf(self):
        #Call When when click on Print PDF
                data = {
                   'ids': self.ids,
                   'model': self._name,
                   'form': {
                       'start_date': self.start_date,
                       'end_date': self.end_date,
                       'vendor_id': self.vendor_id,


           }
        }

              return self.env.ref('purchase_report.purchase_report_view').report_action(self, data=data)



    class PurchaseReportData(models.AbstractModel):

           _name = 'report.purchase_report.purchase_report_view'


           @api.model
           def get_report_values(self, docids, data=None):
               start_date = data['form']['start_date']
               end_date = data['form']['end_date']
               vendor_id = data['form']['vendor_id']

               return {
                   'doc_ids': data['ids'],
                   'doc_model': data['model'],
                   'start_date': start_date,
                   'end_date': end_date,
                   'vendor_id': vendor_id,
               }
```

#### purchase_report_view.xml

```
<odoo>
    <data>
        <report 
            id="purchase_report_view"
            string="Purchase Report"
            model="purchase.report.wizard" 
            report_type="qweb-pdf"
            file="purchase_report.purchase_report_template" 
            name="purchase_report.purchase_report_template"
         />
    </data>
</odoo>
```

#### purchase_report_template_view.xml

```
<odoo>
    <!-- Purchase List Report -->
    <template id="purchase_report_template">
        <t t-call="web.html_container">
            <t t-call="web.internal_layout">
                <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
                    <div class="page">
                        <h1 class="text-left">Purchase List Report</h1>
                        <h2 class="text-left">
                            <t t-esc="vendor_id"/>
                        </h2>
                        <h4 class="text-right">
                            <strong>From</strong>:
                                <t t-esc="start_date"/>
                            <strong>To</strong>:
                                <t t-esc="end_date"/>
                        </h4>
                     </div>
                 </t>
             </t>
         </t>
     </template>
 </odoo>
```